# iPhone - NTLM, Basic and other authorizations using async NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, authorization, nsurlconnection, ntlm

Here's an issue: I need to implement both HTTP basic authorization and MS NTLM authorization. I use asynchronous NSURLConnection so I receive

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

callback. The full code of this method looks like that:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSString* authMethod = [[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod];
    NSLog(@"Authentication method: %@", authMethod);

    NSString *userName = self.login;
    if ([authMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM]) {
        userName = [userName lastElementAfterSlash];
    }
    else if ([authMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodNegotiate]) {
        userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", userName, self.url.host];
    }

    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] <= 1) {
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:userName password:self.password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

        NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
                                                  initWithHost:[self.url host]
                                                  port:0
                                                  protocol:self.url.scheme
                                                  realm:[self.url host]
                                                  authenticationMethod:authMethod];
        [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setDefaultCredential:credential
                                                            forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Authentication error");
        NSLog(@"Failed login with status code: %d", [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)[challenge failureResponse]statusCode]);
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];   
    }
}
```

The two global issues I've met so far using this method:

1) As per Charles sniffer, all the requests to the server are doubled (as per Apple Docs, it's an expected behaviour). However, it leads to lack of performance (two requests instead of just one) comparing to setting header directly, using setValue:forHTTPHeader:.

2) It's being called not for every request. For example, when I'm trying to grab an image from server, it returns 302 (redirect to login web page) HTTP code instead of 401 HTTP code, so this does not work at all.

What I want to accomplish, is to grab the correct Authorization header once and then put it manually in every subsequent NSMutableURLRequest I make. I can compose HTTP Basic authorization manually, it's pretty simple, but I can't compose NTLM header in the same manner, that's why I was relying on didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge: method.

Could you please point me out, how can I receive the Authorization header, that is set automatically by NSURLProtectionSpace, so each request will INITIALLY go authorized?

P.S. I tried to receive it from

```
[connection.currentRequest allHTTPHeaderFields];
```

but it returns an empty array. I'm fighting with that for more than two days, any help will be kindly appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you set the headers directly?  Then, >"2) It's being called not for every request." - this is the behavior of your server. Status code 302 (Found) doesn't mean that authorization is required. For the suboptimal performance, please take a look at: [Use of 100 (continue) Status] (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For basic auth I can set headers directly, it's simply Base64 of "l:p". However, NTML is too tricky. Will appreciate if you could point me to some sample code (C, C++, Obj-c - doesn't matter) which does convert login and pass to NTLM-compatible string for Authentication header. And right, it's behavious of our server - it redirects to the login web page if no headers are YET set to the request, so it doesn't fire auth challenge. Unfortunately it couldn't be modified. Performance will be ok if we can send one request instead of two.

Comment: I think, one or two requests shouldn't make much a difference - as long as you don't send a lot of POST data with the first request, which gets aborted, and as long as the same TCP connection will be used (which should be the case). You may avoid sending POST data in the initial request with a 100-continue header. Probably the best approach to handle NTML is by iOS itself. If there is a particular problem, it will deserve its own question.

Comment: Actually, iOS does handle NTML requests, but the issue is still uncovered - since we can't change an API on the server-side, standard way doesn't work in downloading images - server will redirect me to web-based login form unless I set Auth headers eplicitly in the first request. So that my question will be - how do I extract Auth header from any previous request to set in manually in the request for images?

Comment: Can you use Basic Authentication to login into the server? If yes, then I would suggest to set the corresponding headers in the initial request. Other authorization schemes require a retry of the request. If the server does not accept your initial request or does not respond with 401 in the initial request, but redirects you to some other page, you are probably out of luck. That's also not according HTTP - but I known .. that's how it is.

Comment: A useful link: (http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Basic is working and is covering about 80% of needs - the issue only comes when clients install server under their own intranet network. The issue is that I can't grab headers, that iOS automatically sets with the very first request (after 401 challenge), and set manually to any subsequent request.

Comment: Also, thank you for the link, but as said there " it breaks the case where the redirect is legitimate and not the result of FormsAuth" - if we do force redirect to 401, it will break experience of web app users, which are used to share links to some images, and will be frustrated if server shows them "some weird error" instead of redirect to login, and then "return url" to image they've requested...

Comment: Just a clarification request: if the initial request requires NTML authentication, your delegate method `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:` will be invoked? If that's the case, you should be able to properly authenticate as you desire. Subsequently requests from the same user to the same server may ask the *TLS Session Cache* to retrieve a *Session ID* which is used to short-cut authentication - which may not enter the delegate again.

Comment: As to how authenticate for NTML: you need to provide an *identity* (SecIdentityRef). You may take a look into Apple's sample: "AdvancedURLConnections" - especially: the custom class `Credentials` (which provides "identities"), and the class `ClientIdentityChallengeHandler` which eventually sets the identity for the authentication challenge.

Comment: But of course there's a dilemma: if you always get a 401 - fine for REST APIs, but then browser users will be confused. Otherwise, if you always redirect to the login page - your iOS app gets confused. The solution is certainly, to provide a better web service API which handles both cases.

Comment: @iago849 did you ever come up with a fix for this? I am having the same issue with constantly having 2 connections, 401 and then 200...at my wits end on how to fix. My .NET WebAPI is also using NTLM authentication.

Comment: Yes I did, a long time ago :) actually, there's no way to avoid this behavior, however we did tune our web server to return images instead of 302 error right after 401 challenge. Contact me if there are any issues on the iOS side...

Comment: @iago849  hii ..facing same issue of NTML, may basic question is same ,, how to update the hedaer with NTLM ?? i know we need to pass hedaer something like  "Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="   but not abel to send .  How didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge  method handle this ? please help ....

Comment: @AKSH, hi, I did fight with that stuff for a week but was not able to handle it by adding header "by hands" as it could be easily done with basic authorization. If you need my working implementation of handleAuthentificationChallenge, just let me know

Comment: @iago849 "Contact me if there are any issues on the iOS side" , i am having this issue right now and not finding any work around, actually i am trying to get image through NTLM , didReceiveData delegate infinitely runs , i am confused how can i know my image is completely downloaded. i even tried to close connection from connectionDidFinishLoading but no luck ! Thanks in advance !