# ASIHTTPRequest setDomain -> NSURLRequest equivalent?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm attempting to transition some old code for SOAP requests that relied heavily on the `ASIHTTPRequest` library, to instead use the standard `NSMutableURLRequest` instead. However, I'm running an issue: while with `ASIHTTPRequest` I had access to a `setDomain` function, I can't seem to find an equivalent with `NSMutableURLRequest`.

Does anyone know if there is an equivalent function? I've tried setting it as a header named "Domain", but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up following some advice from: [iPhone - NTLM, Basic and other authorizations using async NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510027/iphone-ntlm-basic-and-other-authorizations-using-async-nsurlconnection)

Turns out, you don't have to set the domain independently; you can set it by passing it as part of the username like so:
`domain\\username`
within an NSURLCredentials object. The exact code I ended up using was:

```
//takes care of HTTP Authentication
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    NSString* authMethod = [[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod];

    if ([authMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM]) {
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"domain\\%@", self.userName]
                                                                 password:self.password
                                                              persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

This all assuming the class is an `NSURLConnectionDeligate`, of course.